# when use jsPDF how can I set coordinates

Tags: javascript, jspdf, jspdf-autotable

We know point(0,0) at the left-top corner, now I want it in the left-bottom corner, how can I do this?

Comment: I do not understand do you want to just switch this two text? Then just switch the texts.

Comment: Now I have two lines even more like "pdf.line(90,250,580,250);pdf.line(90,300,580,300);pdf.line(90,400,580,400);"As we knew the first line in the top ,and the third line at the bottom , I want  the third in the top and the first at the bottom, if more lines they all like this,can you understand that i tell about ,can you have some idears 3Q

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lookup the paper size you're using and use that figure (minus your text height)